# Programmatically refreshing session timeout in ASP.NET MVC4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-timeout

In a nutshell, we want our sessions to last a business day and timeout in the evening. Currently I've set up some simple logic in Session_Start to set the timeout to the number of minutes left until 6pm.

My issue is on refresh the timeout gets set *back* to that value, so if you login at 8am your session will keep refreshing to 10 hours.

Is there any way to override the default logic for refreshing sessions to only set it to X if there is less than X remaining? So like if it gets under 20 minutes remaining I set it back to 20 minutes, but otherwise leave it alone?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: It seems like you have sliding expiration, and want absolute expiration. I know this is easy with Cache items but I am not sure about Sessions. I'll look.

Comment: I was looking at that too, but at some point I do want to extend it. If someone is working late I don't want their session to expire every 20 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Your timeout is set in global.asax only on `Session_Start`, so if a user logs in at 8am, the timeout would be set to 10 hours. If they access your site again within that time frame, their session is extended another 10 hours, because the logic in `Session_Start` does not fire again.

Solution 1 can offer is based off [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36846/Retrieve-All-Active-Sessions-Data). Basically you add every new Session by reference to a List. At 6pm you could iterate through this list and `Session.Abandon()` any open Sessions. This would let you keep all your timeout logic in one or two files.

You can also put a method in your `Page_Load()` that gets the current time and adjusts the `Session.Timeout` property. Here is an example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int timeout = 20;

    var hr = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    var min = DateTime.Now.Minute;
    var time = (hr * 60) + min;

    //1080 minutes = 6pm

    if (time <= 1080)
    {
        timeout = 1080 - time;
    }

    if (time > 1080)
    {
        //1440 minutes = midnight
        timeout = (1440 - time) + 1080;
    }

    Session.Timeout = timeout;

}
```

The code above will expire all sessions at 6pm server time. Try to put this on a master page if you have one.

Comment: "Okay, So if a user logs in at 8am, the timeout would be set to 10 hours. If they access your site again within that time frame, their session is extended another 10 hours." 

Yep that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, which is why I don't want to refresh it unless it goes under 20 minutes.

Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it

Comment: You're welcome. I expanded my answer a bit and added some code, check it out.

Comment: I'm using MVC so I don't have a Page_Load event. The closest thing would be overriding virtual methods from System.Web.MVC.Controller, but I don't know which one refreshes the timeout, was hoping someone did.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int timeout = 20;
  var hour = DataTime.Now.Hour;
  var minutes =DataTime.Now.Minutes;
  var time = (hour * 60) + minutes;
  if (time <= 2000)
  {
    timeout = 2000 - time;
  }
  if (time > 2000)
  {
    //3000 minutes = midnight
    timeout = (3000 - time) + 2000;
  }
  Session.Timeout = timeout;
}
```